# java - overriden method in subclass not being called

Tags: java, overriding

i have a subclass which has a method, process that overrides the one in the parent class but it's calling the method in the parent class, not the one in the subclass.

Parent class

```
public class Records {
    protected String[] process(String table, Integer records, String field) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("***************process- original");
    }

    public void insertRecords {
    Records r = new Records()
    String[] records = r.process(table, records, field);
        String record = records[0];
       /* method implementation */
    }
}
```

Subclass

```
public class RecordsCustomer extends Records{
    @Override
    protected String[] process(String table, Integer records, String field) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("***************process- subclass");
}
```

It prints out '*******process - original' instead of '*******process - subclass'. I am missing something but I can't see it in the code.

Comment: no `extends` in you posted code (so no subclass)? see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

Comment: attach some code how you call the method

Comment: How is `RecordsCustomer` a sub-class of `Records`?

Comment: Sorry left that out when typing it in here, I have added it now

Comment: Don't type. Copy paste. And please add the piece of code where you call your method.

Comment: Show the code where you invoked the process method.

Comment: what exactly is insertRecords now in your code? and you are calling the method in the parent class itself?

Comment: You still haven't copy/pasted your code. The code you show won't compile (look at your `insertRecords` method which is not a method). And you never instantiate a `RecordsCustomer` nor invoke `process()` on it. I'd like to think one of the answers provided solves your problem, but I'm not sure yet what your real problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when creating the object and invoking the method it's:

```
Records records = new RecordsCustomer();
String[] s = records.process(....);
```

And not:

```
Records records = new Records();
String[] s = records.process(....);
```

Comment: I missed that point. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecordsCustomer` class is not subclassing the `Record` class

```
public class RecordsCustomer extends Records {
    protected String[] process(String table, Integer records, String field) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("***************process- subclass");
    }
}
```

Call it this way, it should work as expected

```
Records records = new RecordsCustomer();
records.process("table", 1, "data");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call as shown below (i.e. the real object needs to be of the child class), then it should work :

```
   Records records = new RecordsCustomer();
   records.process("tableName", 10, "customerName");
```

**Note**: for safety, do a clean build before testing.

Answer (score 0):

Create the object this way:

```
RecordsCustomer myObjectName = new RecordsCustomer();
```

or

```
Records myObjectName = new RecordsCustomer();
```

In your code your methods are declaring they return an array of strings, but the method itself is not returning anything, you should return a String array or change de declaration to `void`.